# Haskell implementation of the law of cosines

Tags: haskell, trigonometry

I am trying to implement the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) function, and here is my code:

```
cosC :: [a] -> a
cosC sides
   | length sides < 3          = 0
   | otherwise                 = (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 - z ^ 2) / (2 * x * y)
   where x = head(tail(tail(sides)))
         y = head(tail(sides))
         z = head(sides)
```

But I get two errors:

```
No instance for (Fractional a)
arising from a use of `/'
In the expression: (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 - z ^ 2) / (2 * x * y)
In an equation for `cosC':
    cosC sides
      | length sides < 3 = 0
      | otherwise = (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 - z ^ 2) / (2 * x * y)
      where
          x = head (tail (tail (sides)))
          y = head (tail (sides))
          z = head (sides)
```

and

```
No instance for (Num a)
arising from the literal `2'
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `2'
In the first argument of `(*)', namely `2 * x'
In the second argument of `(/)', namely `(2 * x * y)'
```

Edit: I have fixed the sign typo in the law of cosines above. Thanks to Daniel Fischer for pointing that out.

Comment: You have a sign-error, it should be `(x^2 + y^2 - z^2)` for the law of cosines.

Comment: Well spotted! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're trying to calculate numerical results out of *general types* `a`, that can't possibly work. (It's like trying to build a bridge not just for general road-vehicles but for general *things*, e.g. spaceships, skyscrapers, paper clips and neutron stars). Just add the `Floating` constraint to a:

```
cosC :: Floating a => [a] -> a
```

and you can perform any of the arithmetic operations you need for such a calculation. (`Fractional` is actually enough for this function, but you won't be able to calculate the `arccos` of the result then).

---

Unrelated to your problem, note that there's a much better way to decompose lists in Haskell:

```
cosC (x:y:z:_) = (x^2 + y^2 - z^2) / (2*x*y)
cosC _ = 0
```

is equivalent to your definition. Why are you taking the arguments as a list anyway? That's quite a Lisp-ish thing to do, in Haskell I'd prefer

```
cosC :: Floating a => a -> a -> a -> a
cosC x y z = (x^2 + y^2 - z^2) / (2*x*y)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the extremely useful answer! Actually, it is for a scientific calculator program, and I use RPN, and my stack is represented as a list of doubles.

Comment: Even if your stack is represented as a list, it doesn't mean every single function has to operate on the list. This way every function has to handle the case of the list being too short, etc. -- you'd probably be better off making this function take three arguments, and then using some other general-purpose function to pop three values off the stack and pass them to this one.

Comment: A tip for dealing with compiler messages like this and improving your Haskell-fu: If you do have type signatures on your functions, try _temporarily_ commenting them out, and commenting out anything else that prevents your code from compiling. Then load your code into GHCi and ask it the type of each function (using the command `:t _functionName_`). You may discover that one of your functions has a different type than you thought.

Comment: @shachaf that makes perfect sense! Thanks a lot. mhwombat, yes I have already been trying to incorporate technique into my Haskell programming habits.

Answer (score 5):

`cosC :: Fractional a => [a] -> a`

And this is how you can find out (in `ghci`):

```
*Main> let fun [x, y, z] = (x * x + y * y + z * z) / (2 * x * y)
*Main> :type fun
fun :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well! This has been useful too, but the above answer provides more information to users who may be having or have had the same or a similar problem.

Comment: @Hristo  If you keep the list argument then I suggest you learn from black_dragon's example use of pattern matching the argument (note the `[x,y,z]` to bind x, y and z variables.

Comment: @Hristo, However, note that `[x, y, z]` doesn't give precisely the same behaviour as `x:y:z:_` or `head sides` `head (tail sides)` etc, since `[x,y,z]` will only match lists of length exactly 3, while the other two match length at least 3.